# Method to show dialog

Tags: php

I am making my PM system and I would like to invert so you can see the dialog between you and who you are messaging with..

So if you have pm'ed with eachother previously, it will show under.

Here's an example where I am "Pat", and im about to answer the last pm I got from Diana:

```
***TEXTFIELD***
Yes okay, ill be there at 10pm
****SEND***
Diana- What about the cafetera?
Pat - Sure, when and where?
Diana - Hi, how are you long time no see, wanna meetup?
```

**I wonder how this should be done? Right now you see messages seperatly, and its not displaying any older pm's**

This is what i have **thought** on how should should work:

If diana writes to you, first time like:

> Diana - Hi, how are you long time no see, wanna meetup?

Then there's a normal textfield box that you can type in to answer above it. If you answer on this, it will store the id of the message, Diana message, in the column "dialog", on the row you are about to insert.

It will also update the row, with Diana's message, and apply the id in the column "dialog" there. Then back and forth you pm with eachother, and all the time you both answers through the textfield box above the message, it will always store the first id in the dialog column.

And then to show all the pm's under the textfield, I will just check if theres any `$id` in the column "dialog" of the message. 
If there is then take that `$id`, and get all rows with column dialog `$id` and sort them by date

What do you think about this method? Is there any disadvantages, could this be done easier? A better method you got on your mind?

Answer (score 0):

what you got: `sender_id` `recipient_id` and thats all you need imo

pm_table

```
------------------------------------------------------------
| sender_id | recipient_id | message | created_at          |
------------------------------------------------------------
| 3         | 7            | hi      | 2007-09-08 09:01:00 |
------------------------------------------------------------
| 7         | 3            | hi you  | 2007-09-08 09:03:00 |
------------------------------------------------------------
| 3         | 7            | meet?   | 2007-09-08 09:05:00 |
------------------------------------------------------------
| 7         | 3            | yeah    | 2007-09-08 09:07:00 |
```

user_table

```
-----------------------
| user_id | user_name |
-----------------------
| 3       | john      |
-----------------------
| 7       | darcy     |
```

Query:

```
SELECT send.user_name AS sender,
recipient.user_name AS recipient,
pm.message AS message
FROM pm_table AS pm
JOIN user_table AS sender ON (pm.sender_id = sender.user_id)
JOIN user_table AS recipient ON (pm.recipient_id = recipient.user_id)
WHERE pm.sender_id IN (3,7)
OR pm.recipient_id IN (3,7)
ORDER BY pm.created_at ASC
LIMIT 5
```

Result:

```
--------------------------------
| sender | recipient | message |
--------------------------------
| john   | darcy     | hi      |
--------------------------------
| darcy  | john      | hi you  |
--------------------------------
| john   | darcy     | meet?   |
--------------------------------
| darcy  | john      | yeah    |
```

**EDIT**

a table for topics/dialogs with a reference in pm_table should do the trick

```
SELECT sender.username AS sender,
recipient.username AS recipient,
pm.message AS message,
topic.topic_name AS topic
FROM pm_table AS pm
JOIN user_table AS sender ON (pm.sender_id = sender.user_id)
JOIN user_table AS recipient ON (pm.reciver_id = recipient.user_id)
JOIN topic_table AS topic ON (pm.topic_id = topic.topic_id)
WHERE pm.topic_id IN (1)
```

i'm sure the query can be done better :/

Comment: Yes but i only want to show the dialog if both answered to it, and not made a new pm and write, could you implement that into your answer? ..thats why i thought about the "dialog" column

Comment: do you want your users to have different dialogs with each other? if you writes to me the first time it show only your message. if i answer it shows yours and mine [up to 5 pm in a dialog (LIMIT 5) what can be easily changed]

Comment: Yes different dialogs with eachother. If i message you, and you answer me, it should only display what i wrote and what you wrote on this same "dialog"... So if i message you, and you dont answer through the textfield form, but makes New Message -> type my name -> and then write to me, it shouldnt show my previous message, as you didnt respond to the same dialog, but created a new..

Comment: What is should be stored in topic_table, and topic_name, _id, could you explain that

Comment: yeah topic_name (or subject) and topic_id. i've decided to put that stuff in an extra table because we all love to select subjects like meeting, test, hello or ... so the topic/subject wouldn't be unique and it would be annoying to make them unique (user point of view)

Comment: Why not skip the extra table and just make a column in pm_table called "dialog", "dialog" should have the FIRST message´s id (the one that started the dialog) this way it will be unique too, and simple too. And you mention something about subjects..well no subjects is going to be affected of making this? :P

Comment: yeah a parent_id would also do it ;)